# SonarQube: Unable to import test coverage

Tags: .net-core, sonarqube, code-coverage

I have a SonarQube installation and am running it against a .Net core application with multiple xUnit projects. The SonarQube picks up the bugs and smells fine but like so many people, I can't get the code coverage to complete.

At present, I am generating cobertura coverage XML files using the following command:

```
dotnet test --collect:"XPlat Code Coverage"
```

I then copy these to a centralized directory from each of the test projects and use the following command to run/import the files:

```
dotnet SonarScanner begin /k:"my-project" /d:sonar.cs.vscoveragexml.reportsPaths=".\TestResults\*.xml"
dotnet build
dotnet SonarScanner end
```

According to the logs, the files are found but are not ingested.

> INFO: Parsing the Visual Studio coverage XML report
> C:...\TestResults\5.coverage.cobertura.xml WARN: Could not import
> coverage report '..\TestResults\5.coverage.cobertura.xml' because
> 'Missing root element  in
> C:...\TestResults\5.coverage.cobertura.xml at line 2'

I've confirmed that the files contain valid XML that looks to be correct, but I'm not even sure that SonarQube is supposed to accept cobertura reports.

- Is my approach the way others have gone when trying to get xUnit coverage reports into SonarQube?
- Is there a better way? I'm happy to use OpenCover or similar if that is easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone comes across this in the future, I gave up trying to use the built in coverage in VS and used DotCover. Bit of an easier setup and now seem to have it working to a degree.

- Download/extract dotCover and add the folder to Path
- dotCover.exe --output=AppCoverageReport.html --reportType=HTML dotnet -- test
- dotnet SonarScanner begin /k:"my-project" /d:sonar.cs.dotcover.reportsPaths=AppCoverageReport.html
- dotnet build
- dotnet SonarScanner end

Still having an issue where the test coverage gathering seems to be pulling in too much and as a result is causing an error. Investigating but not related to this question.