# SonarQube test coverage .NET 5

Tags: c#, unit-testing, sonarqube, code-coverage

I want to show test coverage for my .NET 5 unit tests in my local SonarQube instance (on Windows).

```sh
dotnet sonarscanner begin /k:"MyProject" /d:sonar.host.url="http://localhost:9000"  /d:sonar.login="<token>" /d:sonar.cs.opencover.reportsPaths="**\TestResults\*\*.xml"

dotnet build

dotnet test --no-build --collect:"XPlat Code Coverage"

dotnet sonarscanner end /d:sonar.login="<token>"
```

The `dotnet test` command generates the coverage reports as `coverage.cobertura.xml` files in the `<TestProjectDir>.TestResults\<some-guid>\` folder.

In the logs I can see the following warning:
`WARN: Could not import coverage report '<MyTestProject>\TestResults\a4af5812-7f80-469b-8876-3ea0c7c4c98d\coverage.cobertura.xml' because 'Missing root element <CoverageSession> in C:\Users\<Path>\TestResults\a4af5812-7f80-469b-8876-3ea0c7c4c98d\coverage.cobertura.xml at line 2'. Troubleshooting guide: https://community.sonarsource.com/t/37151`

Following the [link](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/coverage-troubleshooting-guide-for-net-code-coverage-import/37151) from the warning message, I can see that only *Visual Studio Code Coverage*, *dotCover* and *OpenCover/Coverlet* are supported. As far as I can tell from their [GitHub page](https://github.com/coverlet-coverage/coverlet), is *OpenCover/Coverlet* is "XPlat Code Coverage".

In my test projects the `coverlet.collector` NuGet package v 3.0.3 is installed.

What am I missing?

I found this related question: [SonarQube: Unable to import test coverage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64914897/sonarqube-unable-to-import-test-coverage) but it doesn't help me because I can't use *dotCover*.

Comment: `Coverlet` generates a report in `cobertura` format by default (as you can see in file name)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error, here's the solution that worked for me.

I had to install the lastest version of `dotnet-sonarscanner` and `dotnet-reportgenerator-globaltool` for this to work. I already had the report generator installed, but needed to update it to use the SonarQube report type.

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-sonarscanner --version 5.2.0
dotnet tool update dotnet-reportgenerator-globaltool -g --version 4.8.7
```

With the `reportgenerator` the cobertura files can be converted to the SonarQube format.

```
dotnet sonarscanner begin /k:"MyProject" /d:sonar.host.url="http://localhost:9000"  /d:sonar.login="<token>" /d:sonar.coverageReportPaths=".\sonarqubecoverage\SonarQube.xml"

dotnet build

dotnet test --no-build --collect:"XPlat Code Coverage"

reportgenerator "-reports:*\TestResults\*\coverage.cobertura.xml" "-targetdir:sonarqubecoverage" "-reporttypes:SonarQube"

dotnet sonarscanner end /d:sonar.login="<token>"
```

Report generator supported file formats: https://github.com/danielpalme/ReportGenerator#supported-input-and-output-file-formats

SonarQube generic test data format:
https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/generic-test/

Answer (score 19):

I think the problem is you are trying to import opencover tests but the tests are in the cobertura format.  You can do this command instead for your tests:

```
dotnet test --no-build --collect:"XPlat Code Coverage" -- DataCollectionRunSettings.DataCollectors.DataCollector.Configuration.Format=opencover
```

And it would likely work.

Comment: Works fine! This should really be mentioned in the official sonarqube docs

Comment: Link to the documentation on passing the format: https://github.com/coverlet-coverage/coverlet/blob/master/Documentation/VSTestIntegration.md#passing-runsettings-arguments-through-commandline

Comment: I think the same can be achieved by passing format parameter like this:
`--collect "XPlat Code Coverage;Format=opencover"`.
Tested with .NET 6 and `coverlet.collector` version `3.1.2`.

Answer (score 0):

I have generated a coverage report by using **"Dotnet-Coverage"** technique.
**Reference Link:** https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analyzing-source-code/test-coverage/dotnet-test-coverage/
**Note:** Here, I have a Visual studio and have a project in .Net 6.

Execute the below command one by one. (Open your project in Visual studio > View > Terminal)

```
dotnet sonarscanner begin /k:"replace_with_your_project_Key" /d:sonar.login="replace_with_your_secret" /d:sonar.cs.vscoveragexml.reportsPaths=coverage.xml

dotnet build --no-incremental

dotnet-coverage collect 'dotnet test' -f xml  -o 'coverage.xml'

dotnet sonarscanner end /d:sonar.login="replace_with_your_secret"
```

**Note:** "replace_with_your_project_Key" & "replace_with_your_secret" - Replace with the data under http://localhost:9000/

Comment: Hi, and how do you processed if tests are not in the same folder as the main project?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. For me, I am keeping a test case project and a source project under the same solution/folder. So it works for me.                                      But if you have a different folder then you can reference a DLL as mentioned under the coverlet section in this link - https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analyzing-source-code/test-coverage/dotnet-test-coverage/                     Hope it might works! But not sure. Thank You