# CodeCoverage using SonarQube scanner and NET5

Tags: .net-core, sonarqube, code-coverage, sonarqube-scan, xunit.net

I have two NET5 xUnit tests projects. On the build server I am generating code coverage report using `coverlet`. These reports are  wired-up to SonarQube scanner based on the guidance  [here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/coverage/)

Here are the steps

begin step

```
dotnet "C:\SonarQubeScanners\sonar-scanner-msbuild-5.1.0.28487-net5.0\SonarScanner.MSBuild.dll" begin /k:"IM" /d:sonar.host.url="http://myhost.com" /d:sonar.login="xxxxxxx" /d:sonar.cs.opencover.reportsPaths="%WORKSPACE%\Tests\MyProject1.UnitTests\TestResults\**\coverage.cobertura.xml,%WORKSPACE%\Tests\MyProject2.UnitTests\TestResults\**\coverage.cobertura.xml"
```

build solution

```
dotnet build "%WORKSPACE%\My.sln" -nr:false
```

run unit tests for two projects and collect data

```
dotnet test "%WORKSPACE%\Tests\MyProject1.UnitTests\MyProject1.UnitTests.csproj" --collect:"XPlat Code Coverage"
dotnet test "%WORKSPACE%\Tests\MyProject2.UnitTests\MyProject2.UnitTests.csproj" --collect:"XPlat Code Coverage"
```

end step

```
dotnet "C:\SonarQubeScanners\sonar-scanner-msbuild-5.1.0.28487-net5.0\SonarScanner.MSBuild.dll" end /d:sonar.login="xxxxxxx"
```

**Question**

1. Each time the unit test runs it create new folder (with Guid Name) under `TestResults`

   - How do I tell SonarScanner to use latest report?
   - Or how do I clean-up TestResult folder before every run, is there a parameter to `dotnet test` command?
2. SonarScanner also throws error wile parsing the generated report

Could not import coverage report 'D:\Jenkins\im\workspace\Tests\MyProject1.UnitTests\TestResults\9c4d50ae-4113-4018-97bb-30d919a9b1e7\coverage.cobertura.xml' because 'Missing root element `<CoverageSession>` in D:\Jenkins\im\workspace\Tests\MyProject1.UnitTests\TestResults\9c4d50ae-4113-4018-97bb-30d919a9b1e7\coverage.cobertura.xml at line 2'

Comment: I found the answer for the second issue 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67086976/sonarqube-test-coverage-net-5

Answer (score 4):

Here are the steps I did doing to get it working

1>First delete the testresult folder before the scanning begins
`rmdir /s /q "%WORKSPACE%\Tests\MyProject1.UnitTests\TestResults"`

2>Modified `--collect` parameters as below to generate coverage report in `opencover` format

`dotnet "C:\sonar-scanner-msbuild-5.5.3.43281-net5.0\SonarScanner.MSBuild.dll" begin /k:"IM" /d:sonar.host.url="myhost.com" /d:sonar.login="xxxxxxx" /d:sonar.cs.opencover.reportsPaths="%WORKSPACE%\Tests\**\TestResults\*\coverage.opencover.xml"`

`dotnet build "%WORKSPACE%\IM.sln" -nr:false`

`dotnet test --no-build "%WORKSPACE%\Tests\MyProject1.UnitTests\MyProject.UnitTests.csproj" --collect:"XPlat Code Coverage" -- DataCollectionRunSettings.DataCollectors.DataCollector.Configuration.Format=opencover`

`dotnet "C:\sonar-scanner-msbuild-5.5.3.43281-net5.0\SonarScanner.MSBuild.dll" end /d:sonar.login="xxxxxxx"`

Comment: The parameter "-- DataCollectionRunSettings.DataCollectors.DataCollector.Configuration.Format=opencover" has made the things so simple!